# iOS Application Installation

Tags: ios, iphone, active-directory, automation, windows-server-2008

I am trying to develop an enterprise environment where the specified app in the app store gets installed in all the iOS devices connected to the company infrastructure, which has a windows based AD to verify the users.
I went through various materials, and I found [over the air profile delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/iPhoneOTAConfiguration.pdf) and few other methods like MDM to push the configuration. But it seems only the configuration can be pushed using these features.

In Apple Configurator and iPhone Configuration Utility, the devices should be connected to the computer physically. I would like to install the app in all the company-owened devices (around 1000 devices) without asking any permission from the user. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This question is off topic since it has nothing to do with programming. I suggest you try [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't take over people's devices without their permission.  Nor can you stealth-install an app.  You can use MDM to register devices on which you can do this, but they need to be registered first. Apple is currently making MDM features more powerful for the Enterprise environment. As an Enterprise developer, you don't have to use the app store for your app - you can distribute it over your own web server.  So even if you go the MDM route, you'll have to register those 1000 devices first.  Once you do that, you have a lot more control.

Comment: Once the devices are registered with Windows MDM server integrated with AD, will I be able to push the apps into the devices as a admin (without the people's permission)?

Comment: After initial installation it's possible I believe, that link should give you all the details you need. If not then enable push notification, as these can now be received in the background, or as an alert, and you app can then load the url for the update by sending it a notification forcing the user to upgrade next time the open the app.

Comment: A good idea! But for the first time? The users will log on with their AD credentials for accessing internet over Wi-fi. Could we able to automate the app installation once they do this?

Comment: New iOS 7 capabilities allow you to push new versions of apps onto registered phones.  There are several MDM vendors, you should contact them and get full information on what they can provide you.

Comment: I am planning to deploy my own MDM Server. If the first installation can be automated.

Comment: Thank you. Today I explored more about MDM. I want to deploy a MDM server on my own (no third party server). I am ready to be a member of Apple Enterprise Developer Program. Till what I understood, once I enroll the program I can get SSL certificate from apple and I will be able to send push notification to the enrolled mobile. Am I right? In addition is there any specific way how I set up the server? One  more serious doubt that I have is that will I be able to install and uninstall apps in the registered devices?

Comment: We send push notifications from our server - what you say is correct. I believe that install and uninstall apps is now in iOS 7 support.  If your question is answered here it is considered good form to mark it so.